# Type-erased allocators in modern C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, type-erasure, allocator

The "classic" STL containers such as `std::vector` and `std::map` take their allocator types as a template argument. This means that `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>` and `std::vector<T, MyAllocator>` for example are considered completely separate types.

Some newer allocator-aware classes like `std::shared_ptr` and `std::tuple` on the other hand use type-erasure to "hide" information about the allocator, so it does not form part of the type signature. However, `std::unordered_map` (which is of a similar vintage to `shared_ptr`) maintains the classic approach of taking an extra defaulted template parameter.

Questions:

1. Is treating `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>` and `std::vector<T, MyAllocator>` as distinct types considered desirable, or is it just a side effect of type-erasure not being a well-known technique at the time the STL was written?
2. What are the downsides (if any) of using type-erasure in this way?
3. Should type-erased allocators always be preferred for new containers?

Comment: Side note: generic type-erased allocators are actually proposed in the [library fundamentals TS](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/memory).

Comment: @user657267: I didn't know about that, thanks for the info, I'll have a read :-)

Comment: The downside of using a type-erased allocator is (usually) performance. When the compiler can see everything, it can inline routines, etc. When you have a type-erased thing, then all it can do is call the routines.

Comment: Further to Marshall's comment... when you've reason to care, you can usually write an allocator type that *internally* uses type erasure to dispatch to any of a variety of concrete allocators, allowing you to use the same outer allocator and avoid distinct container instantiations.  Best of both worlds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Some newer allocator-aware classes like `std::shared_ptr` and `std::tuple` on the other hand use type-erasure to "hide" information about the allocator, so it does not form part of the type signature.

`std::tuple` doesn't use type-erasure at all. A tuple can be constructed with an allocator, but it just (conditionally) passes it to its elements, it doesn't store it anywhere, because a tuple never allocates any memory so has no need for an allocator.

`std::shared_ptr` does allocate memory, so it can use an allocator, which it will store until the control block needs to be deallocated.  Since the control block is already invisible to users and stored on the heap, the allocator associated with that control block is also invisible to users.

So the comparison to `shared_ptr` is not very relevant, because it has completely different uses for an allocator that don't apply to containers.

> 1. Is treating `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>` and `std::vector<T, MyAllocator>` as distinct types considered desirable, or is it just a side effect of type-erasure not being a well-known technique at the time the STL was written?

The original motivation for allocators in the STL was to encapsulate details about the memory model, specifically "near" and "far" pointers of [segmented memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_memory_segmentation). This is why the allocator defines a `pointer` member which the container uses internally. A vector using near pointers must not mix up  addresses of its elements with those in another container using far pointers, for example.

So for the original use, having distinct types was valuable, but that original use  is irrelevant these days.

> 2. What are the downsides (if any) of using type-erasure in this way?

- All function calls have to be virtual (or some other form of indirect call e.g. through a function pointer) and are much harder to inline. This isn't a problem for `shared_ptr` which just allocates some memory once before erasing the allocator type then uses it once more to free the memory, but general-purpose containers might make thousands of allocations.
- A type-erased allocator is much harder to retrieve from the container, making it complicated to create a copy of the container. (Should it use a copy of the allocator? How do you copy something you can't see?) This isn't a problem for types like `shared_ptr` because copying a `shared_ptr` just increases the reference-count, it doesn't allocate anything.
- The object generally needs to be larger by `sizeof(void*)` to store the type-erased allocator. That extra pointer can't be optimized away, even if the allocator is an empty, stateless type such as `std::allocator<T>`. Depending on the type that could mean a 50% or even 100% increase in size compared to being able to exploit the Empty Base-class Optimization to store an empty allocator. This isn't a problem for `shared_ptr` because the allocator isn't needed except when creating or destroying the control block, so it doesn't need to be accessible for the `shared_ptr` to use for other (de)allocations.
- Because a type-erased allocator has to meet an specific abstract interface it has to use raw pointers in its `allocate` and `deallocate` members. This mean you can't use a custom `pointer` type, e.g. a pointer that stores a relative offset to a base address, which is useful for shared-memory allocators as used in Boost.Interprocess.

> 3. Should type-erased allocators always be preferred for new containers?

I would say no. If the allocator is part of the type you can optimize it away for the common cases, while still allowing users of the container to choose a polymorphic allocator that uses type erasure internally, such as the ones in the [Library Fundamentals TS](https://rawgit.com/cplusplus/fundamentals-ts/v1/fundamentals-ts.html#memory.type.erased.allocator)